# get the files name from text file and process them using windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, timestamp

I have a file which has the below content. this is diff list between two tags

type files.txt

A     demo.bat
M     tmp1.bat
M     tmp2.bat
D     test1.bat

here I need only A(addition) and m(modified) files. D(deleted) files should be ignored. How to grep only these files in windows batch. after that I need to get last column which is file names. now we will have only file names. these files are located in the same folder. Now we need to run the scripts one by one by using timestamp. I need to run only modified\created scripts by timestamp. Can someone tell me how to do this using windows batch script?

Answer (score 1):

To get the file names in the file which has `A` or `M` in the first column.

```
$ awk '$1~/^(A|M)$/{print $2}' files.txt
demo.bat
tmp1.bat
tmp2.bat
```

Comment: I need it in Windows DOS batch. it has to be executed in command prompt. Anyway Thanks dude..

Comment: Indeed there is. +1 for answering the question that was actually asked instead of what @smartboy meant to ask.

Comment: guys..I just tagged awk and grep to notify the users..i know it can be done easily in linux. but I need this in windows batch script. It would be helpful if you could share something... Thanks!